# Proving that $\sin(n)$ is not uniformly distributed modulo $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you prove that $\sin(n)$ with $n=0,1,2...$ is not uniformly distributed mod 1?

(This is an exercise in Uniform Distribution of Sequences by Kuipers and Niederreiter.)

Answer (score 7):

You [know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) that the sequence of powers of $e^{i}$ are equidistributed in the unit circle of $\mathbb C$. The sequence you have is obtained from this one by projecting to the imaginary axis. Can you see what happens?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to these things now, and I don't understand a word of your answer (at least from my knowledge of first two sections of first chapter of [Uniform Distribution of Sequences by Kuipers and Niederreiter](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~josefdick/preprints/KuipersNied_book.pdf) after which this exercise appears). I guess, the link you provided to equidistribution theorem simply says that $(n\theta)$ is ud mod 1 for irrational $\theta$. But, I have no idea of how we can "project to the imaginary axis". Can you please make your answer a little more elaborate and better accessible?

Comment: Beautiful idea.