# Does the series $\sum \sin(100n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge?

$$\sum \sin(100n) = \sin(100) + \sin(200) + \dots$$

Comment: This is at least the third time this very question's been asked in the last day.

Comment: See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042726/proof-that-limit-doesnt-exists)

Comment: In the last link amWhy put, the very first answer is very good and basic, imo.

Answer (score 2):

The series doesn't converge since the limit $$\lim_{ n \to \infty}\sin(100n)\ne 0$$

Comment: This may be way easier to state than to prove, in particular for a beginner. It is true, though.

Comment: Apologies about the minor edit.  I have a touchscreen little computer, was upvoting and "missed." The vote could not be changed unless the answer was edited.