# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{i n t}$ does not exist if $0<t<2\pi$

Tags: calculus, limits

How does one prove that? Surely its not that hard to prove and it seems to me I have seen a solution somewhere but now I can not recall where it was.

Comment: Consider $\left|\,e^{int}-e^{i(n+1)t}\,\right|=\left|\,1-e^{it}\,\right|$ and show that this prevents the sequence from being Cauchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I based this proof on [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27293/364722) to a similar question.

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{it\cdot n} = x$ as the limit. Then $x = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{it\cdot (n + 1)} = e^{it}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{itn} = e^{it}x$ But that would mean $e^{it} = 1$ or $x=0$. The case where $e^{it} = 1$ is impossible with the bounds on $t$. And $x\neq 0$ since $|e^{iv}| = 1$ for any value of $v$, meaning the limit must also lie on that circle. (Thank you, Andrei, for mentioning the $x=0$ case.

Comment: Unless $x=0$. You need to check this case as well (trivial).

Comment: Edited, thank you @Andrei

Comment: That's it! Thank you.